# QSerialPort reading signed value

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I'm trying to use QSerialPort class to reading and writing to serial port.
Right now i'm using virtual comports implemented by eltima driver.
I can successfully send bytes like this:

```
QSerialPortInfo info = QSerialPortInfo("COM30");

QSerialPort serial;

serial.setPort(info);

serial.setBaudRate(57600);

serial.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);

char arr[] = {0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD};

serial.write(arr, 4);
```

I'm trying reading like this (I want to read just a single byte; this code is called by timer, if data is ready to be read):

```
virtual uint8_t getByte(void)
{
    char arr[2] = {0};

    int8_t err = qPort.read(arr, 1);

    DEBUG_ASSERT(err != -1);

    if(! isNewByte() )
    {
        onReceiveFinished();
    }

    return arr[0];
}
```

If I send to a virtual port (i.e. to my program) any value less then 128, I get it right (as debugger is showing). However, if I try to send 128 or more, I get value-128 o_o (if I send 153 - I get 25. Not -25 or 103).
That seems like something really odd to me. 
Can anyone see where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was really stupid. QSerialPort is set to 7 databits by default (which seems not very practical, actually), so every received byte had its MSB cut off (like substracting 128).

Still, oddly enough, sending worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not. You wrong do setBaudRate(). It need to do after the port is opening.